# How to know if all the user image get uploaded?

Tags: php, mysql, image, upload, local-storage

I have a website where user can upload images. The code works, it let the user select the image (which is seperate code) and the code below saves it in the local storage. My question is let's say user selected 10 images and one of them didn't get upload (was not the right size or extension etc.) but rest get uploaded. How do I know which image did not get uploaded to local storage and show user that error, so they can re-upload?

My code:

```
$file_array = reArrayFiles($_FILES['userImages']);
pre_r($file_array);

for($i=0;$i<count($file_array);$i++) {

    $name = $file_array[$i]['name'];
    $tmpName = $file_array[$i]['tmp_name'];
    $size = $file_array[$i]['size'];
    $error = $file_array[$i]['error'];
    $type = $file_array[$i]['type'];

    $fileExtension = explode('.',$name);
    $actualExtension = strtolower(end($fileExtension));

    $extensionAllowed = array('jpg', 'jpeg','png','pdf');
    if(in_array($actualExtension, $extensionAllowed)) {
        if ($error ===0) {
            if (size < 1000000) {
                $newFileName = uniqid('', true).".".$actualExtension;

                $root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
                echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
                session_start();
                $_SESSION['last_id'] = mysqli_insert_id($conn);


                $dir = $root.'/userPos/'.$username.'/'.$_SESSION['last_id'].'/';
                $_SESSION['dir_name'] = $dir;

                if(!file_exists($dir) ) {
                    mkdir($dir, 0755, true);
                }
                $fileDestionation = $dir.'/'.$newFileName;
                move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $fileDestionation);


                header("Location: ../profile.php?dirname=".$_SESSION['dir_name']);
            } else {
                echo "Your file is too big";
            } 
        }else {
            echo "There was an error uoloading your file";
        } 
    } else {
        echo "You cannot upload files of this type";
    }
}
```

Comment: You know, I actually explained the gist of this in the comments of your [earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63370759/how-to-only-store-data-in-mysql-when-user-images-get-uploaded). For each file, you're checking `$error = $file_array[$i]['error'];`. So you know if there's an error for that particular file or not. Now, all you have to do is have an array into which you put the details of any file where you find that it failed, including at minimum the filename and the error message. Once you have that information, you can show it to the user quite easily.

Comment: Yeah, I know. But I am not able to do it, so I asked here:(

Comment: Well, what does "not able to" mean? What didn't you understand from what I wrote, exactly? What did you try, and what went wrong? You know how to create an array and populate it, I can see that from your code. So what specifically is the issue? Please show your attempt at implementing this (fairly simple) logic and explain the problem you encountered.

Comment: That's what I did `move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $fileDestionation); if ($error) { header("Location: ../index.php?");
} else { header("Location: ../profile.php?dirname=".$_SESSION['dir_name']);
  }` Even though one of the image does not get uploaded it still send it to me the profile page.

Comment: @ADyson  Also, I don't understand how it goes in `if(error===0)` loop even though there is one error (as one image did not get uploaded.

Comment: $error only covers _one_ upload at a time. Like I said, you need an _array_ of errors which you add to as you go along - every time you check a new image and find a failure, you'd add to the array. Then if that array contains at least one item after you've finished looping, then you'll know that at least one upload failed.

Comment: P.S. `header("Location: ../profile.php?dirname=".$_SESSION['dir_name']);` is not in a logical place - this will cause the redirect even when one upload has completed. You need to wait until you've processed all the images before deciding what to do. i.e. after your `for` loop ends.

Comment: @ADyson Can you please tell me how to create an array of errors? I really don't understand it

Comment: It's just an array, like any other PHP array. Then you add the info of the failed file to it. I really don't know how else to explain, it's just an array. You must have worked with arrays before, surely.

Comment: Jut change this `$error = $file_array[$i]['error'];` to `$error[] = $file_array[$i]['error'];`?

Comment: No, you need a separate array. That's because first, you need to check whether $error actually contains an error code - the code can indicate success or failure (if you didn't know that, then what did you think `if ($error ===0)` was for?). Once you've checked the status, then if it's a failure code you'd add the whole $file_array[$i] object to the error list - so then you've got the file name and the error code (otherwise later on you wouldn't know which file the error referred to).

Comment: Ah, so if there is any error such as not right extension etc, I just add that error message to the `else` statement, so it can store that error with the file name, something like that?

Comment: More or less. So, before your `for` loop starts, declare the empty array e.g. `$errorList = array();`. Then, instead of `else { echo "There was an error uoloading your file"; }`, you would write `else { $errorList[] = $file_array[$i]; }`

Comment: You also need to change `else {
                            echo "You cannot upload files of this type";
                        }` and add a suitable entry to the error list there as well.

Comment: Do we need to refer to the previous question ( already cited by @ADyson ) to make sense of this code here? There are peculiarities in the above code - where does `$username` come from, or the db connection `$conn` ( `mysqli_insert_id($conn);` ) etc??

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius there is certainly more code in that question, but it's not particularly relevant to the question being asked here really.

Comment: @ADyson I tried that what you said but it gives the error that's hard to understand for someone `error4.6.webpchecking errorimage/webpchecking error/opt/lampp/temp/phpANSqEjchecking error0checking error19958` How do I make the error understandable by user?

Comment: That's not an error message. That looks like you possibly just dumped the entire file object, including the paths, rather than selecting items from it? I don't know...what code did you use to get that output exactly? https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php explains how you can interpret the error constants produced by the $_FILES "error" property. The comments even include a ready-made array you can use to associate the errors to the numeric codes, to use in your output. That, plus the filename, should be all you need.

Answer (score 0):

The following is untested but based around code I have been using for several years. I ran a version of this to test and it appears to work OK but whether or nor it meets the objectives posed in both questions is unclear... but there may be things you can take to use in your code.

```
<?php
    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    session_start();
    

    
    if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ){
        
        
        
        $fieldname='userImages';    # the name of the file field in the form.
        $username='geronimo';       # test
        #$username = $username = $_SESSION['userUsername'].$_SESSION['userId'];
        
        
        
        function uploaderror( $error ){
            /* utility function to return info about upload errors */
            switch( $error ) {
                case UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_FORM_SIZE: return "The uploaded file exceeds the MAX_FILE_SIZE directive that was specified in the HTML form"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_PARTIAL: return "The uploaded file was only partially uploaded"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_FILE: return "No file was uploaded"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_NO_TMP_DIR: return "Missing a temporary folder"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_CANT_WRITE: return "Failed to write file to disk"; 
                case UPLOAD_ERR_EXTENSION: return "File upload stopped by extension"; 
                default: return "Unknown upload error";
            }
        }
    
        if( isset(
            $_FILES[ $fieldname ],
            $_POST['_name'],
            $_POST['_desc'],
            $username
        )){
            /* do not have this... is it the db conn? */
            #require '../testing.php';
            
            # pertinent to my dev system
            chdir('../../dbo');
            require 'db-conn-details.php';
            require 'mysqli-conn.php';
            
            
            $extns  = array( 'jpg', 'jpeg','png','pdf' );
            $maxfs  = pow( 1024, 2 ) * 1; # 1Mb ~ MAX File Size
            $root   = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
            $log    = array();
            $errors = array();
            
            
            
            # If images should be deleted if SQL insert fails
            # you can use a `transaction` based approach.
            $conn->begin_transaction();
            $conn->autocommit( false );
            
            
            
            /*
                seems peculiar having both table and column named `_desc`?
                create the `prepared statement` & bind placeholders.
                Execute stmt and find number of rows inserted.. should be 1
            */
            $sql='insert into `_desc` ( `username`, `_name`, `_desc` ) values ( ?, ?, ? )';
            $stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
            if( !$stmt ){
                /* 
                    this should never be reached in production code... 
                    if it is there is a problem with the table schema
                */
                exit('Failed to prepare SQL statement. Check the table design and verify SQL statement is correct.');
            }
            $stmt->bind_param( 'sss', $username, $_POST['_name'], $_POST['_desc'] );
            $stmt->execute();
            
            
            $rows=$stmt->affected_rows;
            $lid=$stmt->insert_id ?: false;
            

            
            
            /*
                If one row was inserted then proceed to process
                all files uploaded. If there is no valid $lid
                variable ( Last Insert ID ) do not proceed as
                it is used to generate folder structure for the
                user.
            */
            if( $rows > 0 && $lid ){
                
                $files=(object)$_FILES[ $fieldname ];
                
                foreach( $files->name as $i => $void ){
                    /* get properties for upload item */
                    $name = $files->name[$i];
                    $size = $files->size[$i];
                    $type = $files->type[$i];
                    $tmp  = $files->tmp_name[$i];
                    $error= $files->error[$i];
                    
                    /* find attributes for file */
                    $ext  = pathinfo( $name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION );
                    list( $width, $height, $type, $attr ) = getimagesize( $tmp );
                    
                    /* Some tests */
                    if( !$width or !$height )$errors[]=sprintf( 'The file "%s" does not appear to be a valid image.',$name );
                    if( !in_array( $ext, $extns ) )$errors[]=sprintf( 'Invalid file extension "%s" for file "%s"', $ext, $name );
                    if( $size > $maxfs )$errors[]=sprintf( 'File "%s" is too large! Size:"%s", Max:"%s"', $name, $size, $maxfs );
                    if( $error!==UPLOAD_ERR_OK )$errors[]=sprintf( 'Error:The file "%s" encountered problems. "%s"', $name, uploaderror( $error ) );
                    if( !is_uploaded_file( $tmp ) )$errors[]=sprintf( 'Warning: The file "%s" might be part of an attack', $name );
                    
                    
                    
                    /*
                        At this stage if there are no errors the file
                        should be moved to it's final location.
                    */
                    if( empty( $errors ) ){
                    
                        $dir = sprintf( '%s/userPos/%s/%s', $root, $username, $lid );
                        if( !file_exists( $dir ) )mkdir( $dir, 0777, true );
                        clearstatcache();
                        
                        $filename=sprintf( '%s.%s', uniqid( '', true ), $ext );
                        $target=sprintf( '%s/%s', $dir, $filename );
                        
                        $status=move_uploaded_file( $tmp, $target );
                        if( !$status ) $errors[]=sprintf('There was a problem saving "%s" as "%s"', $name, $filename );
                        else{
                            $log[]=array(
                                'name'      =>  $name,
                                'size'      =>  $size,
                                'width'     =>  $width,
                                'height'    =>  $height,
                                'filename'  =>  $filename,
                                'folder'    =>  $dir,
                                'status'    =>  $status,
                                'details'   =>  sprintf('"%s" renamed "%s", moved to "%s"', $name, $filename, $dir )
                            );
                        }
                    }
                }
            }else{
                $errors[]='SQL query failed.';
            }
            
            
            if( empty( $errors ) )$conn->commit();
            
            $stmt->free_result();
            $stmt->close();
            
            
            $_SESSION['uploadinfo']=array(
                'errors'    =>  $errors,
                'log'       =>  $log
            );
            exit( header( sprintf( 'Location: ?dirname=%s', $dir ) ) );
            
            
        }else{
            echo 'Error: initial criteria for processing have not been met';
        }
    }
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <title>PHP: Multiple file uploads</title>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <style>
            fieldset{border:none;}
            label{width:80%;display:block;padding:1rem;}
            label > input{float:right;width:80%;}
            .errors{color:red}
            .info{color:green}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data'>
            <fieldset>
                <label>Name: <input type='text' name='_name' /></label>
                <label>Description: <input type='text' name='_desc' /></label>
                <label>Images:<input type='file' name='userImages[]' multiple /></label>
            </fieldset>
            
            <input type='submit' />
            
            <?php
                if( !empty( $_SESSION['uploadinfo'] ) ){
                
                    if( !empty( $_SESSION['uploadinfo']['errors'] ) ){
                        printf('
                            <h1>Errors</h1>
                            <pre class="errors">%s</pre>',
                            print_r($_SESSION['uploadinfo']['errors'],true)
                        );
                    }
                    
                    if( !empty( $_SESSION['uploadinfo']['log'] ) ){
                        printf('
                            <h1>Status</h1>
                            <pre class="info">%s</pre>',
                            print_r($_SESSION['uploadinfo']['log'],true)
                        );
                    }
                    
                    unset( $_SESSION['uploadinfo'] );
                }
            ?>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```